# Play 2.0 Pipe promise to another actor

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

In Akka, you can pipe a future to an actor. How can be it be done under Play 2.0's promise?

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/actors.html#Ask__Send-And-Receive-Future

```
final Future<Result> transformed = aggregate.map(new Mapper<Iterable<Object>, Result>() {
  public Result apply(Iterable<Object> coll) {
    final Iterator<Object> it = coll.iterator();
    final String s = (String) it.next();
    final int x = (Integer) it.next();
    return new Result(x, s);
  }
});

pipe(transformed).to(actorC);
```

Comment: Hi angelokh. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap the `Future<Result>` in a `Promise<Result>` to use it in an async request handler in Play.  Here is an example:

```
public static F.Promise<Result> foo() {

    ActorRef fooActor = Akka.system().actorOf(Props.create(FooActor.class));

    Future<Object> response = ask(fooActor, "message", 5000);

    Future<Result> result = response.map(new Mapper<Object, Result>() {
        @Override
        public Result apply(Object message) {
            return ok("whatever");
        }
    }, HttpExecution.defaultContext());

    return F.Promise.wrap(result);
}
```